# htaccess redirectmatch all of 1 type of file in all subdirectories under a certain level

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect jpgs (that don't exist any more) that scummy picture crawler sites are still trying to access from the picture directory on our old site.

```
RedirectMatch 301 (?i)/Portals/5/.jpg$ http://mysite/hotlink/hotlink.gif
```

does absolutely nothing at all for some reason.

```
RedirectMatch 301 (?i)/Portals/5/.*$ http://mysite/hotlink/hotlink.gif
```

works on jpgs but also on all other files and directories.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Hopefully I'll learn something fundamental about redirectmatch at the same time. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the asterisk on the first one.  It will only redirect for files called #jpg (where # is any character, but only one character.).

The asterisk tells the regular expression to 'match zero or more times on .' and . represents any single character.

`RedirectMatch 301 (?i)/Portals/5/.*jpg$ http://mysite/hotlink/hotlink.gif`

should get you going.

Comment: Thank you! I've found it basically impossible to find a simple glossary of what . * ^ etc in htaccess do exactly so I've trawled through so many 'example's to try to find my exact situation with no success.. I really appreciate you explaining why your solution works.

Comment: You can find what they all mean by searching for 'regular expression' or 'regex'.  Those characters aren't web server specific at all.  Here's the [Wikipedia article on Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and the [Apache httpd docs for regular expressions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html#regex).  Be warned, you may want to gouge your eyes out when writing complex ones.

Comment: Thank you for those links, they will be very useful! I used DOS as a kid so I was under the misconception that .* meant the dot before a file extension and * for wildcard and $ for string.